# what '< >' means in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I have a tiny question, probably an easy one, but I couldn't found googling it. I am working on some code that has something like that:

```
Inserter::Inserter(const data::Set& set){
produces<Info>();
}
```

I don't quite understand what produces means or I am doing something wrong. Here is my interpretation, PLEASE correct me if I am said something wrong:

I had a class Inserter that had an Inserter object, calling from a constant of the object set of class data. Then I produces another object called Info.

am I right?. Please I need some help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics :)

Aka "templates"

> I had a class Inserter that had an Inserter object, calling from a
>   constant of the object set of class data. Then I produces another
>   object called Info.

Kind of :)

You have a class "Inserter".

It's constructor uses a template class "producer".  You instantiate an "Info" kind of "producer".

Here's a good tutorial on templates:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: "templates" is the C++ term; "generics" is not really accurate - although they allow for what is sometimes called the *generic programming* idiom, C++ templates do not behave like C# or Java generics, in a couple of subtle ways.

Comment: Actually, "generics" is a term from Ada (which had the concept long before was introduced into C++).  And yes, Java, C#, Ada and C++ "generics" all have subtle - and significant - differences.  As well as (often) different names :)

Comment: sounds like I was completely wrong. hehe:).. thanks guys for your help!!

Comment: It is definitely not generics. Templates are much more than he simple generic typing that you see in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

They surround a template type.

`produces` is either a function or a class which is templated. The function, or a default constructor, is called.

The specific meaning depends on the implementation. You should read up on how templates work; it is much too involved for a SO answer.

Comment: Nitpick: The function or class is not templated. The function or class *is* a template. Supplying a template parameter creates a new function or class.